# Python 2 - 3 Porting Issues

Tags: python

**Background**

I am trying to learn Python 3. To jumpstart, I am porting a simple Python 2 script of mine to Python 3. The script is a *extremely* simple and I am stuck on a few issues.

**The Issues**

1. `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

I use the socket `.send()` command to send the server's welcome message. When the server attempts to send it, I get the above error. Here is the relevant code.

```
def clientthread(connection):

    #Sending message to connected client
    #This only takes strings (words

    connection.send("Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n")

    #loop so that function does not terminate and the thread does not end
    while True:

        #Receiving from client
        data = connection.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        connection.sendall(data)
        print (data)
    connection.close()
```

And here is the traceback:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function clientthread at 0x1028abd40>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*****/Desktop/Coding/Python 3/Sockets/IM Project/Server/Server v3.py", line 41, in clientthread
    connection.send("Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n")
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

**NOTES:**

I am porting from Python 2.7.3 to Python 3.3

I will add more errors as they arise.

---

**EDIT**

Even though [this] was a great answer, there appears to be an issue - all messages sent to the server are preceded with a `b`. My client is in Python 2 (I will port it later tonight) - could this be part of the issue? In any case, here is the relevant code.

**Client Main Loop**

```
while True:   
    #Send some data to the remote server
    message = raw_input(">>>  ")

    try:
         #set the whole string
         s.sendall(USER + " :  " + message)
    except socket.error:
    #Send Failed
        print "Send failed"
        sys.exit()

    reply = s.recv(1024)
    print reply
```

**Shell Stuff Server**

```
HOST: not_real.local
PORT: 2468
Socket Created
Socket Bind Complete
Socket now listening
Connected with 25.**.**.***:64203
b'xxmbabanexx :  Hello'
```

Comment: "I will add more errors as they arise": you should open new questions for each specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should review the **[Python 3 guide to Unicode](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)** (as well as [Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#deal-with-the-bytes-string-dichotomy)).  `send()` expects bytes, but you are passing it a string.  You need to call the `encode()` method of the string before sending it, and the `decode()` method of the bytes received before printing them.

Answer (score 0):

In python3.*, what socket send and receive is bytes. So you should try:

```
connection.send(b"Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n")
```